# how to use radio fm component as a repeater in android devices

Tags: android, fm-radio

I'm wondering if i can use radio fm component of android devices as a repeater (e.g. Transmit sounds from my android device to other devices via fm) only in software side, without the support of external devices like transceivers or antennas.i wonder if there are APIs that allows to transmit data or something like this, not only able to receive.

Thank you all and sorry for my bad english, i hope i've explained my issue clearly!